# How can I create new data frame that contains the average "mpg" and "disp" for each unique combination of "cyl" and "gear" in the mtcars data frame?

Tags: r

Having some trouble using the unique combinations of "cyl" and "gear" to create three columns that have "cyl", "gear", and "avg_mpg".

I tried `aggregate(mpg~am*cyl, data=mtcars, mean)` but didn't work.

Comment: I'm not clear on why you would use `am` if you want `gear`. What's wrong with `aggregate(mpg~gear*cyl, data=mtcars, mean)`?

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(am, cyl) %>% 
  summarize(mean_mpg = mean(mpg))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'am'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#> # Groups:   am [2]
#>      am   cyl mean_mpg
#>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     0     4     22.9
#> 2     0     6     19.1
#> 3     0     8     15.0
#> 4     1     4     28.1
#> 5     1     6     20.6
#> 6     1     8     15.4
```